# PHP: Where I would save the php file that can I run it in browser

Tags: php

I am php learner, I don't have any idea about where I would save the php file to run on the localhost in browser. If you have any idea please suggest me.

Thanking you

Shailendra singh

Answer (score 4):

You need a web server. See [What do I need?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php)

Additionally, you can try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html):

> XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MySQL, PHP and Perl. XAMPP is really very easy to install and to use - just download, extract and start.

Comment: That was what I was typing :)

Comment: I highly recommend XAMPP, especially for beginners.